# Openrefine - Extract the instance of

Tags: openrefine

I'm using OpenRefine to reconcile some data, and I have the following:

[image]

I succesfuly extracted the entity id from WikiData, but now I want to extract some information about the entity querying into WikiData API. Basically I want to extract the instance of property, so I can now if it is a human, a music band, etc. And some other properties. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Reconciliation Service API](https://reconciliation-api.github.io/specs/) has a concept called [Data Extension](https://reconciliation-api.github.io/specs/draft/#data-extension-service).

The implementation of the [Wikibase reconciliation endpoint](https://gitlab.com/nfdi4culture/ta1-data-enrichment/openrefine-wikibase) implements this part of the specification. So after reconciling your data you can [add properties of your reconciled data as new columns](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/reconciling#add-columns-from-reconciled-values).

For some reason this functionality is **not** in the submenu for reconciliation. You can find it under `"personality" => "Edit columns" => "Add columns from reconciled values..."`.

Instead of using the Reconciliation API for data extension you could also use the WikiData API. This is described in the OpenRefine documentation as [Add columns by fetching URLs](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/reconciling#add-columns-by-fetching-urls). But when available it is imho easier and more comfortable to stay with the data extension part of the Reconciliation API.